React OnClick Event behavior is unexpected
Product Card
function ProductCard ({image, name, stats, id}){

    let dispatch =  useDispatch()
    let quantity = 1

    return (
        <>
        <div className="product-card">
                <div className="product-image-wrapper">
                    <img src={image} alt="" />
                </div>
                <div className="image-metadata">
                    <div className="data-wrapper">
                        <div className="product-details">
                            <div className="product-category">{stats.category}</div>
                            <div className="product-name">{name}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="action-btn-wrapper">
                            <div className="add-to-cart" onClick={()=>{
                                    dispatch(addToCart({name,image,stats,id,quantity}))
                                }
                            }>
                                <img src={addToCartIcon} alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

CART Component
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "../components/header";

import Footer from "../components/footer";
import Checkout from "../components/checkout";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";


function Cart (){
    let cartCount = useSelector(state => state.cart.cart)
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        document.title  = `TRAX- Cart(${cartCount.length} Items)`
    },[cartCount])
    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <Checkout/>
            <Footer/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Cart;

Checkout Component
import React from "react";
import cartImage from '../assets/website-icons/9026048_shopping_cart_simple_icon.svg'
import productImage from '../assets/featured/chair-model.jpg'
import arabicImage from '../assets/featured/arabic-model.jpg'

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CartItem from "../widgets/cartItem";


function Checkout(){
    let cartCount = useSelector(state => state.cart.cart)
    return (
        <div className="cart-wrapper">
                <div className="cart-page-icon">
                    <div className="icon-container">
                        <img src= {cartImage} alt="Shopping Cart Icon" />
                        {/* CART */}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mini-slogan-wrapper">
                    Shop for upto $200 to enjoy<span>FREE SHIPPING</span>.
                </div>

                <div className="cart-table-content">
                    <div className="cart-table">
                        <div className="table-cell header-cell">
                            <div className="table-col-1">Product</div>
                            <div className="table-col-2">Quantity</div>
                            <div className="table-col-3">Price</div>
                            <div className="table-col-4">Subtotal</div>
                        </div>
                        {
                            cartCount.map(({name,image,stats,id,quantity}) => {
                                return <CartItem id={id} productImage={image}  quantity={quantity} productStats={{category : stats.category, color : stats.color}} productName={name}/>
                            })
                        }
                        {/* <div className="table-cell">
                            <div className="table-col-1">
                                <div className="product-entry">
                                    <div className="product-image">
                                        <img src={productImage} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="product-description">
                                        <div className="product-name">Sunny T-Shirt Merch By Zomato</div>
                                        <div className="product-extras">Color: Red, Size : XL, Fabric : Cotton</div>
                                        <div className="product-remove-btn">Remove</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="table-col-2">
                                <div className="quantity-adjuster">
                                    <div className="decrementor">
                                        <img src={decrementor} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="quantity-value">1</div>
                                    <div className="incrementor">
                                        <img src={incrementor} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="table-col-3">$300</div>
                            <div className="table-col-4">$300</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="table-cell">
                            <div className="table-col-1">
                                <div className="product-entry">
                                    <div className="product-image">
                                        <img src={arabicImage} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="product-description">
                                        <div className="product-name">Arabic Scarf - Embroidery Print</div>
                                        <div className="product-extras">Color: Mehroon, Size : Standard, Fabric : Linen</div>
                                        <div className="product-remove-btn">Remove</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="table-col-2">
                                <div className="quantity-adjuster">
                                    <div className="decrementor">
                                        <img src={decrementor} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="quantity-value">1</div>
                                    <div className="incrementor">
                                        <img src={incrementor} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="table-col-3">$120</div>
                            <div className="table-col-4">$120</div>
                        </div> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="checkout-container">
                        <div className="checkout-heading">
                            Cart Summary
                        </div>
                        <div className="selection-group">
                            <div className="selection-option">
                                <div className="selection-indicator-wrapper">
                                    <div className="selection-ball"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="selection-value">Regular Shipping</div>
                                <div className="selection-cost">$12.00</div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="selection-option">
                                <div className="selection-indicator-wrapper">
                                    <div className="selection-balls"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="selection-value">Express Shipping</div>
                                <div className="selection-cost">20.00</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkout-secondary-row" id="checkout-subtotal">
                            <div className="heading-secondary-row">Subtotal</div>
                            <div className="cost-secondary-row">$420</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkout-secondary-row" id="checkout-tax">
                            <div className="heading-secondary-row">Tax</div>
                            <div className="cost-secondary-row">$10</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="checkout-total" id="checkout-total" >
                            <div className="heading-total">Total</div>
                            <div className="cost-total">$430</div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="checkout-btn">Checkout</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout;

Cart Item Component
import React from "react";
import decrementor from '../assets/website-icons/decrementor.svg'
import incrementor from '../assets/website-icons/incrementor.svg'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeFromCart,incrementQty,decrementQty } from "../state-manager/Slices/cartSlice";


function CartItem ({productImage,productName, productStats,id,quantity}){
    let dispatch = useDispatch()
    return (
        <div className="table-cell">
            <div className="table-col-1">
                <div className="product-entry">
                    <div className="product-image">
                        <img src={productImage} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="product-description">
                        <div className="product-name">Sunny T-Shirt Merch By Zomato</div>
                        <div className="product-extras">Color:{productStats.color}, Size : XL, Fabric : Cotton</div>
                        <div className="product-remove-btn" onClick={()=>{
                            dispatch(removeFromCart({productImage,productName,productStats,id}))
                        }}>Remove</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="table-col-2">
                <div className="quantity-adjuster">
                    <div className="decrementor" onClick={()=>{
                        dispatch(decrementQty({id}))
                    }}>
                        <img src={decrementor} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="quantity-value">{quantity}</div>
                    <div className="incrementor" onClick={()=>{
                        dispatch(incrementQty({id}))
                    }}>
                        <img src={incrementor} alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="table-col-3">${300}</div>
            <div className="table-col-4">${quantity * 300}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartItem;

CardSlice
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

let CartSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'Cart',
    initialState : {
        cart : [],
        checkoutTotal : 0
    },
    reducers : {
        addToCart : (state,action)=>{
            
            if(state.cart.length < 1){
                state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload]    
            }else {
                state.cart.map(item => {
                    if(item.id == action.payload.id){
                        item.quantity++;
                    }else {
                        state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload]

                    }
                })
            }
        },
        removeFromCart : (state,action)=>{
            state.cart.map((item, index, cartItemArray) =>{
                if(item.id == action.payload.id){
                    let rar = cartItemArray.splice(index,1)
                    console.log(rar)
                }       
            })
            
        },
        incrementQty : (state,action)=>{
            state.cart.map(item =>{
                console.log(action.payload)
                if(item.id == action.payload.id){
                    item.quantity = item.quantity + 1
                }
            })
        }, 
        decrementQty : (state,action)=>{
            state.cart.map(item =>{
                
                if(item.id == action.payload.id){
                    if(item.quantity > 0){
                        item.quantity = item.quantity - 1
                    }else {
                        console.log('its already nulled out')
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
})

export default CartSlice.reducer
export const {addToCart,removeFromCart, incrementQty,decrementQty}  = CartSlice.actions


I'm using redux for state management, whenever I add to cart, upon the third click the cart count starts doubling up like from 2 to 4 and from 4 to 6 and so on, I have tried a lot and I can't wrap my head around it. Please Let me know what am I doing wrong?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

This happens because you loop over all items in the cart, and for each item, you append the entire cart into the cart, here, in the else:
            state.cart.map(item => {
                if(item.id == action.payload.id){
                    item.quantity++;
                }else {
                    state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload]

                }
            })

What you need to do instead is just update the existing item with the new quantity. Something like this:
            const existing = state.cart.find(item => item.id === action.payload.id);
            if (existing) {
              existing.quantity ++;
            } else {
              state.cart.push(action.payload);
            }

I cannot test the code, but I hope it will help you identify the problem.
Please let me know if this helps.

but what about the else statement, what if that item is not in the cart already, it still doubles up

You are right. I've updated the code.

yeah that worked for me but it was state.cart.push(action.payload) instead of state.cart.push(item), what is the difference between the spread operator and the push method why my code didn't work, was it the map function causing that behavior???

The problem is not in the spread operator itself. The problem was in the loop (map) where you performed the spread. Imagine that you state.cart already has 5 items, and you are executing addToCart .  state.cart.map runs through 5 items, and for each item, it does state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload], which literally says the new cart equals to all items from the old cart + action.payload. And you do this 5 times.
